# Python import from folder

Tags: python, python-import

I have such structure of application

```
mainApp.py
   |_Folder1
       |_fileFromFolder1.py
   |_Folder2
       |_fileFromFolder2.py
```

I want in fileFromFolder1.py import object from fileFromFolder2.py

I know that one of solution is to 
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
but is it possible to make without absolute path

Comment: Is `mainApp.py` a directory or a file? The name suggests a file, the structure suggests a directory (with `Folder1` and `Folder2` subdirectories).

Answer (score 1):

You need(not strictly need in Python3, but still really really should have) `__init__.py` files in directories you would like to import code from. An `__init__.py` file makes the difference between a plain directory and a Python package

```
mainApp.py
   |_Folder1
       |__init__.py
       |_fileFromFolder1.py
   |_Folder2
       |__init__.py
       |_fileFromFolder2.py
```

Comment: You can use relative imports so `fileFromFolder1` accesses `fileFromFolder2` without paying attention to the names of higher level packages, e.g. in `fileFromFolder1.py`: `from ..Folder2 import fileFromFolder2`

Comment: Late night education for me.